# In parity, how can I delete the last blocks I downloaded without corrupting the database?

Tags: blockchain, parity, linux, blockchain-fork, parity-wallet

I have found the blockchain data in parity. I go to overlayrecent folder and from there to the db folder. It looks like the blocks are the .sst files.

How can I delete the last blocks I downloaded without corrupting the database?

For example when I just deleted the last .sst file, and then went to terminal and ran parity, I got "Client service error:

```
Client(Database("Invalid argument: You have to open all coloumn families. Column families not opened: col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0"))".
```

Comment: Just currious, what is the goal of doing this ?

Comment: I thought that maybe since I had a block after the hardfork, that was the reason I couldn't sync anymore on the ETC chain after updating the client. Everything stopped at 3,000,001. I believe I have found this is not the problem now.